# How to load an already trained XGBoost model to run on a new dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

New to XGBoost so forgive me. I've trained a model on the Boston housing dataset and saved it locally. Now, I want to load the model, and use a new dataset similar in structure to predict their labels. How would I go about doing this in Python 3.6? I have this from the training step so far:

**UPDATED TO TRY PICKLE INSTEAD**

**UPDATE 2: Added cause of error, preprocessing.**

**UPDATE 3: See below comments for answer**

```
    print('Splitting the features and label columns...')
    X, y = data.iloc[:,:-1],data.iloc[:,-1]

    print('Converting dataset to Dmatrix structure to use later on...')
    data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X,label=y)
    #....
    # Some more stuff here.
    #....
    print('Now, train the model...')
    grid = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=data_dmatrix, num_boost_round=10)

    # Now, save the model for later use on unseen data
    import pickle
    model = pickle.dump(grid, open("pima.pickle.dat", "wb"))

    #.....after some time has passed

    # Now, load the model for use on a new dataset
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open("pima.pickle.dat", "rb"))
    print(loaded_model.feature_names)

    # Now, load a new dataset to run the model on and make predictions for
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Boston Housing Data.csv', skiprows=1))

    # Split the dataset into features and label
    # X = use all rows, up until the last column, which is the label or predicted column
    # y = use all rows in the last column of the dataframe ('Price')
    print('Splitting the new features and label column up for predictions...')
    X, y = dataset.iloc[:,:-1],dataset.iloc[:,-1]


    # Make predictions on labels of the test set
    preds = loaded_model.predict(X)
```

Now I get the traceback:

```
        preds = loaded_model.predict(X)
    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
```

Any ideas? I'm noticing that when I print the loaded_model.feature_names I get:

```
['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
```

...but the actual .csv file has an extra column 'PRICE' which was appended before the training and used as the label during training. Does this mean anything?

I didn't think I'd have to go through the whole train and test split thing because I'm not looking to actually re-train the model, just use it on this new dataset to make predictions, and show the RMSE from the actuals on the new dataset. All the tutorials I see online don't go in to the step of implementing the model on new data. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: the ```model``` did not load properly. That's the error. I am assuming you are using tensorflow @MattWilson, please check if ```model.summary()``` works to see if the model is indeed loading

Comment: @LazyCoder Hey, looks like you're right, but not sure how to fix it. I tried using print(model.summary()) but now says object has no attribute 'summary'. Is there a better way to save/load trained models? Well, I'm using SkLearn/XGBoost.

Comment: Check if model file isn't corrupt. You may have to retrain if that's the case, which I hope not. Check whether the filepath is correct, just to be sure. Most bugs are silly bugs.

Comment: @LazyCoder I'm still running into a wall. Take a look at my update above and see what you can see? Thanks!

Comment: google  colab dude. It's tough to debug with given info]

Comment: @LazyCoder https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BeJDP6hTkvpw2-BJadfYyb-2mPxorJAC check it out when you can. I have a part at the top to reference where to find my local GraphViz exe just a heads up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same preprocessing used on the training set over the test set in order to make any kind of predictions. Your problem is because, you have used DMatrix structure in training, which is required BTW.

```py
print('Converting dataset to Dmatrix structure to use later on...')
    data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X,label=y)
```

but failed to use that preprocessing on testing set. Use same preprocessing for all of training set, validation set and testing set. Your model will be golden.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Forgot to do that with the new testing set. So I now have the function "preds = loaded_model.predict(data_dmatrix)", and i also had to take out the "skiprows=1" from the read_csv function when loading the new .csv file for testing/predictions. Thanks again!!!